# WebSocket issue : Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

i am building project in spring boot and i want to implement chat application logic into my project i am using websockets and here is my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SamepinchApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Bean
    public EchoEndpoint echoEndpoint() {
        return new EchoEndpoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextAware endpointExporterInitializer(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return new ServletContextAware() {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SamepinchApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SamepinchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and EchoEndpoint

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/api/v1/chat/{username}")
public class EchoEndpoint {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EchoEndpoint.class);
  private static final Set<Session> sessionsSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
  private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

  @OnOpen
  public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session, @PathParam("username") String uname) throws IOException {
      session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection established with session id "+session.getId());
      sessionsSet.add(session);
      sessions.put(uname, session);
      System.out.println("Connected with: " + session.getId());
    log.info("Connected with: " + session.getId());
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onWebSocketMessage(Session session, String message) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("getting message......");
      System.out.println(message.substring(message.indexOf(":",0)+1));
      String[] mesgArray = message.split(":");
      System.out.println(mesgArray[0]);
      Session sess = (Session) sessions.get(mesgArray[0]);
      if(sess != null)
          sess.getBasicRemote().sendText(message.substring(message.indexOf(":",0)+1));
//    sendMessageToAll(message);
  }
  @OnClose
  public void onWebSocketClose(Session session) {
      System.out.println("Closed: " + session.getId());
    log.info("Closed: " + session.getId());
  }
  @OnError
  public void onWebSocketError(Session session, Throwable error) {
      System.out.println("Error (from " + session.getId() + "): " + error.getMessage());
    log.info("Error (from " + session.getId() + "): " + error.getMessage());
  }

  private void sendMessageToAll(String message){
      for(Session s : sessionsSet){
          try {
              log.info("send from qasim siddiqui");
              log.info(s.getId());
              s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
}
```

this code is working fine when i am running code in ecllipse but when i deployed it to tomcat it gives me this exception

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/samepinch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register @ServerEndpoint class: class com.samepinch.socket.EchoEndpoint
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoint(ServerEndpointExporter.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoints(ServerEndpointExporter.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ServerEndpointExporter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Multiple Endpoints may not be deployed to the same path [/api/v1/chat/{username}]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:199)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:271)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoint(ServerEndpointExporter.java:145)
    ... 24 more
```

on tomcat it tries to create multiple endpoints and i am not getting any solution . Can anybody help me!

i am using this dependency for websocket

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: What versions of Spring Boot and Spring Framework are you using? If you're using something that's up-to-date, there shouldn't be any need for the `endpointExporterInitializer` – it's only needed to work around https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12340.

Comment: i am using 1.2.3.RELEASE spring boot

Comment: i have removed endpointExporter initializer still it is not working

Answer (score 2):

you remove

```
@Bean
public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
    return new ServerEndpointExporter();
}
```

Tomcat not need this

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple end points in production,you should need echo end point in development not in production..so configure according to the environment

```
if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
   //  then create echo point
}
```